# i have 5 elements and I choose one of them that when i click on that will be red but when i click to other elements it also be red

Tags: javascript

```
var s = document.getElementById("1");
if( s.src != "img/clear.gif") {
    document.getElementById("4").src = "img/red.gif";

}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, please provide proper details like what's the exact issue and what outcome is expected

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item" id="item1" onclick="colorRed('item1')">click me to paint me red</div>
        <div class="item" id="item2" onclick="colorRed('item2')">click me to paint me red</div>
        <div class="item" id="item3" onclick="colorRed('item3')">click me to paint me red</div>
        <div class="item" id="item4" onclick="colorRed('item4')">click me to paint me red</div>
        <div class="item" id="item5" onclick="colorRed('item5')">click me to paint me red</div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function colorRed(param){
            document.getElementById(param).style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

If I got your question right, here is the solution. Instead of red color, you can add or replace your image code. I made a function with one parameter who will update only clicked element.